# How do I make my custom directory(folder) in Android 10's Internal storage and store my data?

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I am perfectly able to generate a PDF and store it in my custom made folder in Android SDK's version=<28 but as of Android 10

```
 customFolder = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "TimingNotezz");
 customFolder.mkdirs();
```

`customFolder.mkdirs()` is false which means folder is not created, so

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) 
{
    //I want to implement the code to create and store contents in a custom directory specifically for 
    // Android 10 here
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance. I would love to have different suggestions.

Comment: You mentioned internal storage in title, but you obtain external storage directory in your code. So, what exact kind of storage do you want to use?

Comment: And by the way, do you have permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest, and do you grant it to your app? It may be the reason your `mkdirs` fails

Comment: Android 10 is Q, not R. While you could use `android:requesLegacyExternalStorage` to support 10, that will not work with 11. I recommend that you switch to the Storage Access Framework, using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to let the user choose a base location under which you can place your content in a sub-tree.

Comment: Yes I have given the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the manifest and I have granted it to the app. `mkdirs` works fine and as expected below API 29 but dosen't work in API 30. And the above code creates a folder named  "TimingNotezz" in the Internal Storage.

Comment: Anything would work but I prefer to create a folder in the Internal Storage as I've just started development @Steyrix

Comment: I have given android:requesLegacyExternalStorage = "true" in the manifest @CommonsWare.  Can you provide the documentation link or any sort of video link so I may learn android:requesLegacyExternalStorage as you mentioned and by the way thank you for the correction

Comment: @RandyOrton: Sorry! I had a typo there. It is `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` (I missed the `t` in `request`). See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage and https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#scoped-storage for more.

Comment: Folks IDK but how  `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            customFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "TimingNotezz");
            customFolder.mkdirs();
        }`  Worked just fine on Android 10 , just to make sure I installed the app on my real Samsung A50 which is Android 10 and this thing works , It actually creates a folder on my Internal storage( I do not have an sd card ). I infer that  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose a storage location. Then after that create your "TimingNotezz" folder in it using storage access framework. Also your file you should create using saf.

Comment: Can you provide code examples or at least documentation links?